How to fix "Configs are not cached" error of laravel-health checking?
Using laravel-health on laravel site I got error on checks:
Optimized App
Configs are not cached.

Debugging the code I found in vendor/spatie/laravel-health/src/Checks/Checks/OptimizedAppCheck.php :
if ($this->shouldPerformCheck(self::CONFIG)) {
    if (! app()->configurationIsCached()) {
        return $result->failed('Configs are not cached.');
    }
}

In .env I set :
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false

Looking code I found :
public function getCachedConfigPath()
    {
        return $this->normalizeCachePath('APP_CONFIG_CACHE', 'cache/config.php');
    }

Which options have I to check not to have this error on dev/production configuration ?
"laravel/framework": "^10.48.7",
"spatie/laravel-health": "^1.28",

Thanks in advance!

I have no idea about what Laravel Health is, but just looking at the source code you shared, I think you need to also run php artisan config:cache on your deployment script, so you cache the configuration. You can also run php artisan optimize, it will cache routes, events, views, and configs, if I am not missing any other
